# Primefaces Editable Datatable example from official site primefaces.org does not work

Tags: primefaces

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBean.carsSmall}" id="carList" editable="true">  

    <f:facet name="header">  
        In-Cell Editing  
    </f:facet>  

    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{tableBean.onEdit}" update=":form:messages" />  
    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{tableBean.onCancel}" update=":form:messages" />  

    <p:column headerText="Model" style="width:125px">  
        <p:cellEditor>  
            <f:facet name="output">  
                <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />  
            </f:facet>  
            <f:facet name="input">  
                <p:inputText value="#{car.model}" style="width:100%"/>  
            </f:facet>  
        </p:cellEditor>  
    </p:column>
```

Simple example from official site of primefaces  does not work.

the error is

> javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException: /faces/default.xhtml @36,106
>    Event:rowEditCancel is not supported.

Comment: WHich version of primfaces you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. But I found the solution that I was using version 3.1 of primefaces. And this version not supports rowEditCancel event.

Answer (score 0):

In-Cell Editing data table is supported in primefaces 3.5 and primefaces 4.0 upgrade needed

Answer (score -1):

Make sure in your bean, you have a method defined like this:

```
public void onCancel(RowEditEvent event) { 
//...put your logic here
}
```

Comment: Read the error message carefully!!! it is related to the event name defined in the xhtml, not the method name in the java code